# Newbie Python Question about tuples

Tags: python, tuples, cx-oracle

I am new to Python, and I'm working on writing some database code using the `cx_Oracle` module.  In the [cx_Oracle documentation](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/html/module.html) they have a code example like this:

```
import sys
import cx_Oracle

connection = cx_Oracle.Connection("user/pw@tns")
cursor = connection.cursor()

try:
    cursor.execute("select 1 / 0 from dual")
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError, exc:
    error, = exc.args
    print >> sys.stderr, "Oracle-Error-Code:", error.code
    print >> sys.stderr, "Oracle-Error-Message:", error.message
```

My question has to do with where the "error" object is created.  What does the "`, =`" do?  I tried searching Python documentation, and search engines don't work very well when you're searching for operators.   :-)

I know that the exc.args is a singleton tuple, but I just don't understand the "`, =`" syntax.  If I remove the comma, I get the error message, "`AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'code'`".

Can someone point me to where this is documented?  Thanks!

**EDIT:**

This works without having to unpack the tuple:

```
import sys
import cx_Oracle

connection = cx_Oracle.Connection("user/pw@tns")
cursor = connection.cursor()

try:
    cursor.execute("select 1 / 0 from dual")
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError, exc:
    print >> sys.stderr, "Oracle-Error-Code:", exc.args[0].code
    print >> sys.stderr, "Oracle-Error-Message:", exc.args[0].message
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
error, = exc.args
```

This is a case of [sequence unpacking](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

A more readable way to write the same, and the style I personally favor, is:

```
[error] = exc.args
```

There are two bits required to understand the previous example:

1. When the left hand side of an assignment is a recursive sequence of names, the value of the right hand side must be a sequence with the same length, and each item of the RHS value is assigned to the corresponding name in the LHS.
2. A one-item tuple in python is written `(foo,)`. In most contexts, the parenthesis can be ommitted. In particular, they can be omitted next to the assignment operator.

Answer (score 5):

[http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/tut/node7.html](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/tut/node7.html#SECTION007300000000000000000)

Look for "sequence unpacking" in section 5.3.

Answer (score 4):

The comma serves to unpack the tuple, i.e. it extracts the single item of the tuple, and binds it to `error`. Without the comma, you would bind the tuple itself, rather than its content.